# I have this error: " xport 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' "

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, frontend

** I have react-dom v^18.2.0**

> And My Code:

import Home from "./Home";
import Navebar from "./Navbar";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

```
function App() {

  
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navebar/>
        
        <div className="content">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using react-router-dom v6 or greater than in place of **Switch** use **Routes** :-

```
import Home from "./Home"; import Navebar from "./Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {

  return (
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Navebar />
    <div className="content">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

please follow react-router-dom updating documentation from v5 to v6 :-

> [doc-link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes)